# How do I repair damage to this ‘paneling’?

Tags: wood, hole, damage

just hoping for some advice on how to repair this?

Not sure what the material even is but is paneling of some sort on the stairs. Was drunk and stumbled down my elbow few out and went through rather easily.

I have no DIY knowledge or experience so fingers crossed for some hep!! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Look into repairing drywall. The process would be similar.

Comment: Like [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/136668/1683).

Answer (score 3):

If that is a painted surface, one approach would be

- Cleanly cut out the damaged area using a utility knife, jab-saw or similar tools.
- Clean up the edges. Perhaps using sandpaper.
- Fill the void using expanding foam.
- Cut-off the excess foam using something like a filling knife.
- Apply a surface filler and allow to harden.
- Sand absolutely flat.
- Paint.

If that isn't a painted surface you'll probably never get an invisible repair without replacing the whole panel.